# Parse one field from nested Json to String Value

Tags: android, json, sqlite, gson

i have one field nested JSON in my API response :

```
"ratingBest": 10,
"reviewCount": 1,
"coordinate": {
    "latitude": "-7.2768",
    "longitude": "112.7927"
},
...
```

I save above data to Android local DB using ORMLite, but i want just one field `coordinate` to be `String`. Cause Gson automatically convert in specific type.

I already try to use a class field type as String. But still not work

Any workaround for that?

Thank you

Comment: How are you trying to acomplish the situation? Where are you saving the model with Gson?

Comment: Not yet implemented. But for normal response i use ORMLite helper in Android, and just call `create()` method with Json response from API as parameter. And i want one field `coordinate` saved as `String` cause Gson is automatically convert every each of response to specific type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're not going to process the latitude/longitude pair in any way, since you made no mentions on it, and your "row" is supposed to be something like:

```java
final class Location {

    final int ratingBest = Integer.valueOf(0);

    final int reviewCount = Integer.valueOf(0);

    @JsonAdapter(PackedCoordinateTypeAdapter.class)
    final String coordinate = null;

}
```

Take a look at the `@JsonAdapter` annotation that binds a specific type adapter to the field. The type adapter may look like this:

```java
final class PackedCoordinateTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<String> {

    private static final String DELIMITER = " ";
    private static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    private static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";

    private static final Pattern delimiterPattern = compile(DELIMITER);

    // Keep private stuff private as much possible, Gson can access it  
    private PackedCoordinateTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final String packedLatitudeLongitude)
            throws IOException {
        final String[] split = decode(packedLatitudeLongitude);
        out.beginObject();
        out.name(LATITUDE);
        out.value(split[0]);
        out.name(LONGITUDE);
        out.value(split[1]);
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public String read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        String latitude = null;
        String longitude = null;
        in.beginObject();
        while ( in.hasNext() ) {
            final String name = in.nextName();
            switch ( name ) {
            case LATITUDE:
                latitude = in.nextString();
                break;
            case LONGITUDE:
                longitude = in.nextString();
                break;
            default:
                throw new MalformedJsonException("Unexpected: " + name);
            }
        }
        in.endObject();
        return encode(latitude, longitude);
    }

    private static String encode(final String latitude, final String longitude)
            throws MalformedJsonException {
        if ( latitude == null ) {
            throw new MalformedJsonException("latitude not set");
        }
        if ( longitude == null ) {
            throw new MalformedJsonException("longitude not set");
        }
        return latitude + DELIMITER + longitude;
    }

    private static String[] decode(final String packedLatitudeLongitude)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        final String[] split = delimiterPattern.split(packedLatitudeLongitude);
        if ( split.length != 2 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot parse: " + packedLatitudeLongitude);
        }
        return split;
    }

}
```

Demo:

```java
final Location response = gson.fromJson("{\"ratingBest\":10,\"reviewCount\":1,\"coordinate\":{\"latitude\":\"-7.2768\",\"longitude\":\"112.7927\"}}", Location.class);
System.out.println(response.coordinate);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(response));
```

Output:

> -7.2768 112.7927
>   {"ratingBest":10,"reviewCount":1,"coordinate":{"latitude":"-7.2768","longitude":"112.7927"}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var a = {
  "ratingBest": 10,
  "reviewCount": 1,
  "coordinate": {
    "latitude": "-7.2768",
    "longitude": "112.7927"
 }
}

var b = {
  "ratingBest": 10,
  "reviewCount": 1,
  "coordinate": JSON.stringify(a.coordinate)
}
```

now store b

Comment: Haha i ask about Json in `Android`, not Javascript. In Android i use ORMLite to store response from API automatically using `create()` method. And i still not found yet to except one field to be saved as `String`. I hope you understand what i mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following way:

```
myObj = {
    "ratingBest": 10,
    "reviewCount": 1,
     "coordinate": {
     "latitude": "-7.2768",
     "longitude": "112.7927"
       }
    }
var latitudex = myObj.coordinate.latitude;
var longitudex = myObj.coordinate.longitude;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but i ask about in Gson implementation. Java

Comment: @fanjavaid you can follow this [generating-json-from-java-objects](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html#generating-json-from-java-objects)